# How to get photos off my iphone when connecting to new machine?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

I have an iphone 5s. I set it up on one computer a few months ago.

Now I connect it to a new laptop, iTunes starts and shows me the following:

```
Welcome to Your New iPhone

Would you like to set up this iPhone as a new iPhone
or restore all your information from a previous backup?

x) Set up as a new iPhone
x) Restore from this back up: (My iPhone)
```

I'm not sure that I want to do either - I have photos on my phone I want to transfer from the phone to my laptop. I'm worried if I set up as a new iPhone, it might erase what's on the phone maybe. Same goes for restoring - it might wipe everything back to the last restore save point.

Which should I do? Is there a way I can get around this and just get my pictures?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not erase anything. That dialog is only asking whether you want to restore a backup or not. When you click on "set as new", the only thing that will happen is that it will syncronize the iPhone with iTunes.

To import the pictures, you can use Image Capture. It will download all the photos in the fodler you select.